# ng-bootstrap close mutliple drowdowns simultaneously

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I have two dropdowns in my Angular application:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input
    id="startDate"
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    aria-label="Start date"
    dlDateTimeInput
    [ngModel]="startDate"
  />
  <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button
        class="btn btn-outline-primary"
        id="startDateDropdown"
        ngbDropdownToggle
      >
        <i class="oi oi-calendar"></i>
      </button>
      <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="startDateDropdown">
        <div style="width: 360px">
          <dl-date-time-picker
            [(ngModel)]="startDate"
            (change)="startDateSelected($event)"
            minuteStep="15"
          >
          </dl-date-time-picker>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="input-group">
  <input
    id="endDate"
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    aria-label="End date"
    dlDateTimeInput
    [ngModel]="endDate"
  />
  <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button
        class="btn btn-outline-primary"
        id="endDateDropdown"
        ngbDropdownToggle
      >
        <i class="oi oi-calendar"></i>
      </button>
      <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="endDateDropdown">
        <div style="width: 360px">
          <dl-date-time-picker
            [(ngModel)]="endDate"
            (change)="endDateSelected($event)"
            minuteStep="15"
          >
          </dl-date-time-picker>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to close the dropdown menu with this:

```
import { ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { NgbDropdown } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";

[...]

export class ParentComponent {
  @ViewChild(NgbDropdown)
  private dropdown: NgbDropdown;

  public startDateSelected(event: DlDateTimePickerChange<Date>): void {
    this.startDatePicked.emit(event.value);
    this.dropdown.close();
  }

  public endDateSelected(event: DlDateTimePickerChange<Date>): void {
    this.endDatePicked.emit(event.value);
    this.dropdown.close();
  }
}
```

> The Problem

The problem is that only the first dropdown is closed but the second isn't.

How can I simultaneously close the start dropdown and the end dropdowns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close all the dropdowns you need to use ViewChildren, not ViewChild.  This will return a query for all elements or directives that match the selector.

```
@ViewChildren(NgbDropdown)
dropdowns: QueryList<NgbDropdown>;

startDateSelected(event: DlDateTimePickerChange<Date>): void {
  this.startDatePicked.emit(event.value);
  this.closeDrownDowns();
}

endDateSelected(event: DlDateTimePickerChange<Date>): void {
  this.startDatePicked.emit(event.value);
  this.closeDrownDowns();
}

private closeDropDowns() {
  this.dropdowns?.forEach(x => x.close());
}
```